# Asymptotically stable vs Essentially Asymptotically Stable

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I'm having a difficult time understanding these terms when dealing with dynamical systems (e.g. visualizing what these terms mean for a dynamical system). The dynamical systems I'm dealing with involve heteroclinic networks. Some terminology from this paper I'm reading:

**Definition 1:** A heteroclinic cycle is a collection of equilibria $\left\lbrace Q_1,\cdots,Q_n \right\rbrace$ of some ordinary differential equations (let's suppose it's $\dot{x}_i = f_i(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$), together with a set of heteroclinic connections $\left\lbrace \gamma_1(t),\cdots,\gamma_n(t) \right\rbrace$ where $\gamma_j \rightarrow Q_j$ as $t \rightarrow -\infty$ and $\gamma_j \rightarrow Q_{j+1}$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$, and where $Q_{n+1} \equiv Q_1$.

**Definition 2:** Let $C_1, \cdots, C_m$ for $m\geq 2$ be a collection of heteroclinic cycles. We say that $N = \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$ forms a heteroclinic network if there do not exist networks (or cycles) $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that $N= N_1 \cup N_2$ where $N_1 \cap N_2 = \emptyset$

**Definition 3:** We call a flow invariant set $X$ essentially asymptotically stable (e.a.s) if there exists a set $C$ such that given any number $a \in (0,1)$ and any neighborhood $U$ of $X$, there is an open neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $X$ such that:

1. all trajectories starting in $V \setminus C$ remain in $U$ and are asymptotic to $X$
2. $\mu(V \setminus C)/\mu(V) >a$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure

Definition 1 makes sense to me. Definition 2 basically says (to my understanding) nothing is disjoint and that there's always a way to essentially trace a line through heteroclinic connections to get from one equilibria to another. Definition $3$ to me is confusing. I don't understanding how to think of this definition conceptually in terms of a dynamical system. The paper says that e.a.s can be thought of as "not asymptotically stable but which attracts almost all trajectories that start nearby".

I don't understand how the measure-theoretic definition correlates with that interpretation, nor am I understanding the difference between asymptotically stable and e.a.s. I'm not experience in topology which might be why I'm struggling to wrap my head around this. One other quote I don't understand: "One necessary condition for a cycle to be asymptotically stable is that $W^u(Q_i)$, the unstable manifold of $Q_i$, lies in $W^s(Q_{i+1})$, the stable manifold of $Q_{i+1}$. All cycles within a heteroclinic network violate this condition so none are asymptotically stable." Why is this condition violated?

Answer (score 0):

Condition 3 is saying that the measure of initial conditions NOT asymptotically stable (this set is called C) is small, since the condition 2 of definition 3 means that the ratio $\dfrac{\mu(V\backslash C)}{\mu(V)}$ can be made as arbitrarily close to 1 (by choosing a as close to 1 as desired).
If set C was empty, then X will be asymptotically stable. But definition 3 allows for a nonempty but arbitrary small measure set C, and hence X is essentially asymptotically stable.

Comment: Thank you. I think what's confusing to me is understanding how something (e.g. heteroclinic cycle) can attract almost all trajectories that start nearby but is not asymptotically stable. Is that why they say "Almost all", i.e. there's a set of measure arbitrarily close to 0?

Comment: If it attracts ALL, then it is asymptotically stable. If attracts all but a small measure, it is essentially asymptotically stable.